# how to insert email separator line in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In outlook, when you reply to an email, it appends the email thread to the bottom of the email document but inserts a blue line across to separate and demarcate the start/end of the email.

I want to copy and paste the email body from another email complete with the "From, Sent, To, CC, Subject" headers and then insert the blue line to create the consistent email boundaries.

How can I do that?

(email here and there... seriously lack of words to describe)

Answer (score 22):

You can create different styles of lines by typing specific characters three times, followed by Enter.

[image: screenshot1]

You can also create graphic lines using Borders and Shading.

[image: screenshot2]

Source: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Insert-horizontal-lines-9bf172f6-5908-4791-9bb9-2c952197b1a9

Comment: The character shortcut is great because it also works on Outlook for Mac (while the others do not...)

Answer (score 6):

In Outlook message editor go to the **Insert** tab and click the **Horizontal Line** button in the **Symbols** group (in the right side of the ribbon).

Then right click on the newly inserted line and select **Format Horizontal Line**,

[image: format horizontal line]

select Blue, Accent 1, Lighter 60% as the colour and change the line height to 1,

[image: line colour & height]

your inserted line should look almost identical to the default line.

[image: line comparison]

Comment: The automatic line created by Outlook is not the same as the symbol horizontal line though.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on Actions/Edit Message.
2. Select and highlight 2 lines; the line that has the "From" and the line above it.
3. Go to "Format Text" tab, on the Paragraph ribbon tool, click on the drop-down for borders, it is the last tool to the right at the bottom, right below the AZ tool.
4. On the drop-down for borders, go to the last menu item for "Borders and Shading".
5. Click the drop-down for Color
6. Choose last option in the Color drop-down which is "More Colors".
7. You will get a pop-up screen for Colors. On the Custom tab, enter the following numbers for Red 181, Green 196, Blue 223.
8. Click OK to close the Colors pop-up.
9. Now you are back to Border and Shading pop-up screen, click OK to close it.
10. Again on "Format Text" tab, on the Paragraph ribbon tool, click on the drop-down for borders to open it again.
11. On the drop-down for borders, click "Inside Horizontal Border". The blue line will get added in the previously selected color. Clicking this menu item more than once will toggle the blue line on/off.

Comment: For steps 6-7, instead of the custom color, mine uses the second Theme Color under white, the one just above the one shown in @CaptainSlock's answer.

Answer (score 2):

For Office 2016:

1. On the Insert tab of the Office 2016 ribbon, select Horizontal line.
2. Right-click on the line and select Picture.
3. This is where things depart from @thims' (2007?) solution, as the lines are different in 2016:

   - Leave the Height at 1.5 pt.
   - Select "White, Background 1, Darker 15%" as the color.
   - Change the alignment to left (I found this lined up more accurately with the default line).

[image: Picture of line properties]

This results in a line that isn't noticeably different when separated by lines of text:

[image: Picture of results]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question, per se, but I offer a shortcut for this.  I was wishing that the given answers were more simple, and there probably isn't a more simple answer than these.  I suggest following the other's advice.  Once you have the horizontal rule (HR) formatted to your liking use the Auto-correct feature of MS Word to recall the recorded, and pre-formatted HR.

1. Highlight the HR
2. activate the Auto-Correct dialog
3. add the formatted text to your auto-correct registry with a code that you feel is memorable and usable.

I chose the the code "%----" because I have a series of such code and I use "%" to prefix them.  To use, type your code and make a carriage return.