# How to create a horizontal line that looks exactly like the thread separator line when replying to an email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I came across this, but it doesn't really do what I want:

[how to insert email separator line in outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/721280/how-to-insert-email-separator-line-in-outlook)

When you reply to a message in Outlook 2007 and 2010 (and probably older and newer versions), it inserts a light blue horizontal line just above the message you're replying to.  This line is different than the ones you can create with `---` or `Insert > Horizontal Line` in that it can't be manipulated.  You can cut it out by selecting a range of text, but, when you paste, it disappears.  I want to emulate this line exactly.

The reason why is because I am compiling a convoluted message thread into a summarized thread before I forward it out to the recipients.  The OCD part of me wants it to be exactly the same as the reply separator.

**Update:**  In looking at an email's source code, the horizontal line is apparently a `<div>` with a top border:

```
<div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'></div></div>
```

How to get this into my Outlook 2007 email is a chore, though.  There is apparently a tool that let you edit an email source code directly, but it only works for 2010 and 2013.  I've also found that I can save an email's source as an HTML file, edit it, and then attach it as text, but editing an email's HTML in a text editor while conforming to the HTML document structure of Outlook is quite a chore, so I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 2013 at the moment but I think that this should work in 2007 and 2010 versions. Though I am not sure whether the steps below renders the 2007 or 2010 version... long time ago that was :)

1. Click the Table button [image] in the **Paragraph** group of the **Format Text** tab, and then open the **Borders and Shading** dialog from the drop down menu
2. Select the line style, color and width in the **Borders** tab (experiment to get exact width and color). Press **OK**
3. Just delete one-cell table created
4. Position your cursor to where you want to have the line and click on the [image] button one more time
5. Select the Bottom border (or Top border)
6. You should get the horizontal line inserted

Another way is to create an empty single-cell table, remove the borders except the top or bottom one, and select the color and the line width :)